# Antlr 4 - C#: Raise Custom Events on Parsing Errors

Tags: c#, events, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm using Antlr 4 with C# as target, and I want to raise an event when a syntax error occurs.

**my grammar**

```
/*
 * Parser Rules
 */

text : term+  EOF
;

term : a1 a2 a3
;
a1: ....
...
...
```

When error occurs, I want the parser behavior to ignore input text until next term found.
The raised event should get the whole ignored text, the line and column of error position and the error message.

I extended the base class BaseErrorListener:

```
public class DictionaryErrorListener : Antlr4.Runtime.BaseErrorListener
{
    public event EventHandler<ParsingErrorEventArgs> ParsingErrorOccured;

    protected void OnParsingErrorOccured(int line, int column, string errorMessage, string text)
    {
        EventHandler<ParsingErrorEventArgs> handler = ParsingErrorOccured;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new ParsingErrorEventArgs(line, column, errorMessage, text));
        }
    }

    public override void SyntaxError(Antlr4.Runtime.IRecognizer recognizer, Antlr4.Runtime.IToken offendingSymbol, int line, int charPositionInLine, string msg, Antlr4.Runtime.RecognitionException e)
    {
        OnParsingErrorOccured(line, charPositionInLine, msg, ignoredText);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Am I on the right way?
- How to get the ignored text?

Answer (score 2):

The `IAntlrErrorListener` interface is used for *reporting* errors (and certain other non-error conditions related to parser performance). The `IAntlrErrorStrategy` interface is responsible for error handling/recovery. The default implementation of this interface is [`DefaultErrorStrategy`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.html). In general, this is one of the more advanced features of the runtime. I worked to provide a reasonable level of detail in the documentation for the [Java runtime's `DefaultErrorStrategy`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/DefaultErrorStrategy.html), but it will *definitely NOT be easy* to get right.

Rather than try to implement a better error handler, I normally take a different strategy with my grammars:

1. Relax the grammar - this means I intentionally allow the grammar to match input which is *syntactically* incorrect for the language.
2. I then treat the incorrect syntax as *semantic* errors, and use a listener or visitor to report the errors after the parsing is complete.

If you start with a "strict" grammar (one which only allows the exact syntax of your language), then the relaxing process involves allowing additional syntax and at the same time adding a semantic error to the post-parsing phase to address the specific incorrect syntax you allowed.

Comment: Thanks for these points, but even if i used ANTLRErrorStrategy, How to get the ignored text? Should i use AST?